# Updating from 19.04 to 20.10

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I had to keep using 19.04 for a while after it was discontinued for a variety of reasons. I would now like to move up in the world to 20.04. I have tried following a number of paths, for example the sequence of steps which is described here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Lubuntu/comments/g3390k/1904_the_repository_standard_repo_no_longer_has_a/

In brief, this means, eg:

```
sudo sed -i 's/disco/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

The error message I get, which seems to be reproduced across the internet, is as follows:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I guess it's been long enough now though that somebody somewhere must have found a fix to this, no? Does anybody know what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: When a release goes EOL (like *disco* or 19.04 has), many PPAs are emptied, so some of your expected errors are to be expected; as *disco* is EOL.  What each *team* or maintainer does at EOL is up to them; but some don't want to encourage using EOL releases, nor having users ask for support for the EOL release - thus their being cleared out.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades